# Local Web Page with Dynamic connection to an excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Could we create a local web page that is not published connected dynamically with excel worksheet..so if any changes in the excel worksheet will be directly reflected to the web page content with no need for refresh button ? any refrence about this with sample showing the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to save the Excel sheet as an HTML file in the location where it will be read.

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:= "mypath\myfile.htm", FileFormat:=xlHtml
```

This could be done in the `Worksheet_Change` event.

**EDIT**: The quick and dirty solution above doesn't fit your needs. But you could customize it so it does. For example, instead of saving the Excel sheet itself as HTML, you could have the `Worksheet_Change` event write out the relevant cells to, for instance, an XML file, which would then be read by your web page. You could set the web page to refresh automatically.

Or, write and embed a Java app that reads from your Excel workbook file using e.g. http://poi.apache.org/

You're going to have to consider different approaches and decide what is best for you.

Comment: Thanks brother. This is actually brilliant idea. but is there away for real connection without the need to save because save i think will write to ROM and take time while connection doesn't save and will not get replacement prompt. I really like your answer but real connection will be stronger I think..thanks alot brother.

Comment: + this solution, if the html file is open will need to close and open it again...any idea!!

Comment: It's better to program the local html page to retrieve data dynamically from the excel sheet so we could get benefit of web page programming controls.

Comment: Hi guys...is it really hard question? do you know where should I go to have the answer?...upset :[

Comment: Now now, dont' get upset. Have you had any ideas or tried anything yourself?

Comment: Hi Francois, I tried asp coding but I didn't know how to establish a dynamic connection. I needed to set time to refresh or a command button which is not the required...also tried Excel vba form table and faild...thanks for help and yes i'm trying to keep some hope :)

Comment: Welocme brother Francois again, really special thank for your effort.Solution with refresh is not really perfect for real connection. I'think the other with java and intermdiate app or asp.net may do this. the idea is exactly like yahoo finance page which when the market is open the prices reflect directly what is in the server, only the prices in the page changes with no refresh, like a server is connected in between so any changes in the database will change the related variable in the web page. I'll go try java and in'sha allah will get it and be back,,, really thanks man.

Comment: To enhance getting the solution faster, a practical example will be excellent, we have a local excel file with worksheet having cell("A1") value "3", and we have a local html that retrieve cell ("A1") value, we would like to apply the Apache POI so we could read ("A1") and if it's changed it will update it directly...It will be really magnificent step.